# How to deploy Yo Angular application to Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku

I created a yo angular AngularJS application, and I was wondering how I can deploy it to Heroku.

I haven't been able to find anything online that pertains to a yo angular application. The folders/structure is exactly as yo angular. I have not touched the default Gruntfile.js.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I have tried to follow that tutorial, but I can not get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Followed this tutorial: http://jaketrent.com/post/yeoman-app-on-heroku/ for the most part. The only thing that is causing an issue nowadays is the fact that Express is on a new version ie. 4.x.x, where as the tutorial is written for Express 3.x.x. Downgrading Express did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this really excellent tutorial and it worked perfectly:
http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2014/07/13/how-to-create-an-angular-app-using-yeoman-and-deploy-it-to-heroku/